# Conditional call to second async function, based on data collected before the first async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have some data in a array.

```
let data = ['firstData', 'secondData'];
```

The first object (firstData) always exists, secondData could be null. So I always use that to call my async function like:

```
myAsyncFunction(data[0]).then(result => {
    //do something here
});
```

If `data[1]` exists, I wanna call `myAsyncFunction` with `data[1]`.

My current solution is with nested promises. Like this:

```
myAsyncFunction(data[0]).then(result => {
    return result;
}).then(result => {
    if(data[1] !== null){
        myAsyncFunction(data[1].then(resultTwo => {
        //dostuff with data
      });
    }
});
```

I don't really like this solution, but it does work. It must be a better way tho. `result` is always a object. I tried `Promise.all` but it does not work. I think it's a problem with "race condition" of some sort (I am on thin ice here).

Is my current solution the only one?

Here is what myAsuncFunction looks like:

```
myAsyncFunction(personData){
    return new Promise<any> ((resolve, reject) => {

        //Assingen private variables

    secondAsyncFunction(somePersonData).then(result =>
     {

                    //Do some sync stuff

          return someNewData; //not a promise
     })
         .then(thirdAsyncFunction)
         .then(data => {
              resolve(data);
         })
         .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
     });
});
```

Comment: So I have a few questions... your if statement is checking that it's not equal to null... does that mean that your array might be data = ["firstData", null]? Also, you may want to try to do something with Promise.map. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html

Comment: Hi! Correct, data[1] could be null sometimes. I'm not using blubird, I'm using ES6 promises. I think there is a difference (?).

Comment: If you're simply looking to figure out when they're all done, and they might be null, you could create a map from the data array like so....

let data_promises = data.map(function(data){
  return data ? myAsyncFunction(data) : Promise.resolve();
 });

Then call Promise.all(data_promises);. This pretty much checks if the value exists (null is of course falsey) and will create a Promise that resolves immediately if it is null

Comment: If you could share the error message or code for when you tried `Promise.all`, it would be appreciated. If there's a race condition, does that mean that the first promise must be finished before the second promise begins?

Comment: I don't get any error message. But I get two objects back in Promise.all. The problem is both objects are based on data from the second object (data[1]).

Comment: @mintermasher It sounds like `myAsyncFunction` is buggy. In theory, each invocation should be completely independent.

Comment: @4castle, in _ALL_ cases?

Comment: Regarding `myAsyncFunction`, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @mintermasher The code you have looks correct in structure. By "buggy", I mean that your function is stateful, when it shouldn't be. You've got some kind of closure or global variable which is making the function stateful, and the results of the last invocation is bleeding into the results of the first invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is designed to be used when you have a dynamic number of promises in an array, and you want to combine them into a promise which resolves when all of the promises in the array have resolved.

According to your use case, you should be able to use it like this:

```
data = data.filter(x => x !== null);

Promise.all(data.map(myAsyncFunction)).then((results) => {
    const [resultOne, resultTwo] = results;
    if (resultTwo) {
        // handle resultTwo
    }
    // handle resultOne
});
```

Comment: When I use Promise.all I only get result based on the second value. As I said, I think it has something to do with race condition.

Comment: In that case, you may have a promise leak (*ie. your async function resolves/rejects itself before it's actual execution is completed*)

Comment: Oh... That could explain it. What is the best way to find out if there is any promise leaks?

Comment: @4castle, you may want to do `data.filter(i=>i).map(myAsyncFunction)`. Since `myAsyncFunction` should **not** execute when `data[x]` is `null`

Comment: @mintermasher Only way I know is reading the code, adding `console.logs` at different parts of the promise chain (and see which print statements execute in the wrong order!)

Comment: @AP, I just wanna be clear - is there 100% a promise leak, or could Promise.all not work in some cases?

Comment: Without seeing the function body I cannot say for certain, but NO `Promise.all` will always execute **all** the promises inside, and ***will return*** their resolved callbacks. UNLESS any of them `reject` or `throw` an exception, in which case the `Promise.all` will reject on the first failure, and none of the successes (`pending` or `completed`) will be reported

Comment: @mintermasher I've edited my answer above/below with a code block, which I believe should not have any leaks.

Comment: @4castle, this would probably work. But when I call myAsyncFunction like that, "this" is not defined.

Comment: @mintermasher If `myAsyncFunction` is a method of an object, then surround it with an arrow function like `x => obj.myAsycFunction(x)`. You could also use `obj.myAsyncFunction.bind(obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `data` is known statically before the promise result, you don't need to put the condition inside the `then` callback - you can make the whole chaining conditional:

```
var promise = myAsyncFunction(data[0]);
if(data[1] !== null){
    promise.then(result =>
        myAsyncFunction(data[1])
    ).then(resultTwo => {
        //dostuff with data
    });
}
```

In general, notice that nesting is not a bad thing, it is required when you want to branch control flow. Just don't forget to always `return` your promises from all (callback) functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply do:

```js
const stuffOnlyRelatedToSecondData = result2 => /*do something*/

myAsyncFunction(data[0]).then(result => {
    if (data[1] === null) {return null}
    return myAsyncFunction(data[1]).then(stuffOnlyRelatedToSecondData) 
}).then(/*Anything to do after [1] or [1,2]*/)
```

This way you can use the same chain and the two possible cases will look like:

```
myAsyncFunction(data[0]) --> END
myAsyncFunction(data[0]) --> myAsyncFunction(data[1]) --> END
```

### Edit:

It seems that `myAsyncFunction` may have a promise leak, try using something like this instead:

```
const myAsyncFunction = personData => {
    //Assigning private variables
    return secondAsyncFunction(somePersonData).then(result => {
        //Do some sync stuff
        return someNewData; //not a promise
    })
    .then(thirdAsyncFunction)
}
```

We can write it this way because `secondAsyncFunction` kicks off a new Promise, hence we don't need another Promise wrapper around it. And the catch can be put in the parent Promise chain itself which executes `myAsyncFunction`

Comment: I tried the code within the edit. I understand way wrapping it again is unnecessary. But the problem is that secondAsyncFunction is called with the same value twice. Even tho before returning secondAsyncFunction all values are correct.

Comment: Hm. I create a variable (lets call it y) before returning secondAsyncFunction. 

If I console.log(y) (inside secondAsyncFunction)  I get the correct value of the property .prop (for example). But when I console.log(y.prop) - I get the wrong value?

Comment: @mintermasher It sounds like you need to do a bit more debugging, until you can narrow down the problem to a [mcve], with actual code.